# implementation for coppersmith matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, linear-solver, mathematica, matrix-equations

Is there any online implementation for the coppersmith matrix multiplication I have searched alot but can not find any?  and if there is not any why is that Isn't this algotithm much faster than strassen in very large square matrices in the range of 100000 to millions,  from what I understand the only downside of it is that  the constants of running time is high

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm. The Copper-Smith algorithm is a galactic algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_algorithm, which means it doesn't worth to implement it.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer thanks very much is there any chance that you may know Virginia Vassilevska Williams algorithm and if it is implemented and used or not?  thanks for your time and help

Comment: I don't think so... Even for Strassen and Winograd which are more popular ones, there are few implementations available online. Is this related to your research or you just simply looking for an efficient way to multiply large matrices? I mean you want to develop a new algorithm to beat for example Strassen or Winograd or you just looking for a better performance to multiply large matrices?

Comment: Have you thought about what it even just takes to store a dense matrix of size 100,000 to a million? You'll end up with $10^{10}$ to $10^{12}$ entries, each of which takes at least 4 bytes. Where do you get this much memory from?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth We have some nodes in our supercomputer that have ~ 4TB RAM but I agree it is unreasonably large that just probably storing one matrix of this size would inflate the memory...

Comment: i am trying to learn more about these algorithms to improve running time of training data on the big companies servers so space is not an issue but i found very little info online

Comment: @AloneProgrammer  even on big company servers like nvidia or google?

Comment: I understand what you mean here but remember you don't need spacecraft to go home from your work office when you can take a taxi or drive with your car. Same thing here... Cause you have a spacecraft already in your garage, it doesn't mean you should use it even when you want to go to grocery... As a result, based on my experience with all these fancy algorithms: the best approach to handle exa-scale matrix multiplication is to invest on creating a really efficient parallel framework based on MPI to get a good performance based on naive algorithm. It's my suggestion based on experience...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer thank you very much sir you helped me a lot best of luck to you